# Flowable-idm not able to provide access to access Privileges to group

Tags: docker, ldap, flowable

Thanks for looking into my question.

I am new in flowable application.

1. Login to **flowable-idm** portal, create a user **ankit** and then create a group **claimManager** where i added **ankit** user.

[image: group caimManager]

2. In **flowable-idm** portal, go to Privileges section -> Access modeler application -> remove **ankit** user from user(if exist) -> go to group tab -> add group **claimManager**.

[image: privileges section]

3. Login to **flowable-modeler** portal with usename: **ankit** and this is issue where i am not able to login as i added group having **ankit** user.

But when i try to add **ankit** user to users tab in **flowable-idm** and try to login in **flowable-modeler** with **ankit** user, then i am able to login with **ankit** user.

Please find detail description over link: https://forum.flowable.org/t/flowable-ldap-integration/5190/4

===========================

Edited part 2

===========================

[image: claimManager group]

==============================

edited part 3

=================================

[image: 503 to user ankit]

Comment: Is there a need to remove 'ankit' user from access modeler application and add only group 'claimManager'?

Comment: Yes if there is ankit user available in users in privileges section, yes need to remove it. Is there any issue with this?

Comment: Actually we add ankit user in group claimManager and we need to access ankit to access modeler  application.

Comment: can you add screenshot that says `claimManager` is part of modeler privileges? (not the edit screen)

Comment: what error does it give when you try to login?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I am getting credential error while login with ankit user at modeler portal. Please find ScreenShot in edited question of expected claimManager group.

Comment: screenshots say you have group `503` that has privileges. can you show what users are present in group `503`?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh First screenshot already showing this.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Please find 503 to user ankit with LDAP configuration in edoted question.

Comment: Ok I was trying to verify you have the correct groups. Could you start a completely fresh (LATEST version) flowable instance and see?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I have flowable-idm and flowable-modeler image of latest version.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Is there any issue with configuration. Did you check configuration in https://forum.flowable.org/t/flowable-ldap-integration/5190?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh When i run without LDAP configuration then everything working fine but i want to work with LDAP. Can you please check configuration at https://forum.flowable.org/t/flowable-ldap-integration/5190

Comment: I don't have idea about LDAP. right now am working to get flowable connection to keycloak

Comment: @Akki Can you please provide me sample of flowable with LDAP docker configuration file?